# How to solve $y^{(n)}=e^y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve this differential equation $$y^{(n)}(x)=e^{y(x)}$$

for general $n$?

So far I've obtained:
$$\begin{align}
n&=1~, & y'(x)=e^{y(x)}, ~&~~~ y(x)=-\log( -c_1 - x ) \\
n&=2~, & y''(x)=e^{y(x)},~&~~~ y(x)=\log \left(-2 c_1 e^{\sqrt{c_1 \left( c_2 + x \right)^2}} \left( e^{\sqrt{c_1 \left( c_2 + x \right)^2}} + 1 \right)^{-2} \right) \\
n&=3~, && \text{???}
\end{align}$$
Already at $n=3$ Mathematica's [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) is unable to solve it.

Comment: Please check that my edit didn't mess up your math.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya yes

Comment: Well, you see yourself that it gets very bad very fast.

Comment: For $n=2$ $$y(x)=\log\left (\frac {1} {2} c_ 1\left (\tanh^2\left (\frac {1} {2}\sqrt {c_ 1 (c_ 2 + 
                 x) {}^2} \right) - 1 \right) \right)  $$ looks a bit nicer.